# LIbrary not found but ldd shows it

Tags: fortran, intel

I'm compiling a piece of fortran code with intel compilers, everything goes smooth until I try to execute the compiled executable which gives a:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[FAIL]
```

However, the missing library library is linked to the executable, as shown by *ldd*

```
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f176d848000)
        libimf.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00007f176d350000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f176d04a000)
```

Any ideia on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the executable? Are you using a script?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it from a script...

Comment: Probably the environment looks different in that script. Maybe, your LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting is not correctly set there?

Comment: You will have to set the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the script. For csh use `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or for bash use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`